# What should I call this function composition?

Tags: python, math, functional-programming

What should 'foo' be called, given the following?

x.items is a set, y.values is a set.

function a(key) returns an ordered list of x.items

function b(x.item) returns a single y.value

Define foo(a, b), which returns a function, d, such that d(key) returns a list of y.values defined by: map(b, a(key)).

This feels like a fairly common and generic function composition but I don't know what to call it.

Comment: x.items is a set? And a(key) gives you an ordered list of x.items? Based on what? How does "key" map to a subset of x.items()

How is the mapping between x.item to y.value done? sets doesn't have position of it's members, so it can't be position.

It might be common and generic, but it makes no sense. :)

Comment: Functions 'a' and 'b' are arbitrary mapping functions.  The actual implementation generates them based on configuration files and the current time.  x.items could be set(1,2,3) while y.values could be set(4,5,6).  For example, a(100) = [1,2], a(150) = [2,3], a(200) = [1].  b(1) = 5, b(2) = 6, b(3) = 4.  foo(a, b)(100) = [5, 6]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function a(key) returns an ordered list of x.items
 function b(x.item) returns a single y.value
```

Except for the ordering, a() is in practice a filter, i.e. it "filters" or "selects" items from x.items according to a key. b() is a normal map, or function. Thus, I would choose for 'foo' the name "composeFilterWithMap", or "composeSelectorWithMap" or a similar name.

Answer (score 1):

I would call it **function compositor** or something like that

Answer (score 1):

I would call that function **permuted_values**

What you are doing is equivalent to iterating over a hash map using a permutation based on your key.

Answer (score 0):

The synergy engine.

Comment: Gussey it up however you want Trebek.  What matters is, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Here's are example names for a, b, and foo that might help (I don't like these, but they're sort of like what I'm getting at):

```
items_by_key(key)

value_by_item(item)

values_by_key(items_by_key, value_by_item)
```

Comment: Your should edit your question and put this in there instead of putting it in an answer.